# A specific data structure

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory

Well, this question is a bit specific but I think there is some general idea in it that I can't get it.

Lets say I got K servers (which is a constant that I know its size). I have a program that get requests and every request has an id and server id that will handle it. I have n requests - unknown size and can be any number.

I need a data structure to support the next operations within the given complexity:

**GetServer** - the function gets the request ID and returns the server id that is supposed to handle this request at the current situation and not necessarily the original server (see below).

**Complexity**: **O(log K)** at average.

**KillServer** - the function gets as input a server id that should be removed and another server id that all the requests of the removed server should be passed to.

**Complexity**: **O(1)** at the worst case.

--

**Place complexity for all the structure is O(K+n)**

--

The KillServer function made me think using a Union-Find as I can do the union in O(1) as requested but my problem is the first operation. Why it's LogK? Actually, no matter how I "save" the requests if I want to access to any request (lets say it's an AVL tree) so the complexity will be O(log n) at the worst case and said that I can't assume K>n (and probably K

Tried thinking about it a couple of hours but I can't find any solution.
Known structures that can be used are: B+ tree, AVL tree, skip list, hash table, Union-Find, rank tree and of course all the basics like arrays and such.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the ways you access and use the requests? It seems that a serverid-organized dictionary of queues supporting serverid-remapping with a second layer of AVL trees for requestid-based lookup might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union-find starting with requests partitioned by server should work. You start with each request pointing to it's server, then you union together the servers (not the requests). Thus, the amortized cost of GetServer would be O(alpha(K)) rather than O(alpha(n)), where O(alpha(K)) << O(log K).

Comment: Why do I need to union the servers? What their union means? Lets say I got a request ID, how can I find the request itself (O(logn)?) before going to the pointer of it to the server? And how I do the KillServer operation in that case in O(1)?

Comment: I was assuming you are passed a pointer to the request. If requests are identified only by an id, you can use hashing to find the actual pointer representing the request, find that request's initial group (one pointer traversal), and then use union-find to find the current group. KillServer is just a pointer link if you start with pointers to the two groups that are being unioned.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a data structure consisting of two parts:

- a finite map (AVL tree, etc.) from client IDs to *job* IDs
- a union-find data structure to group job IDs and to label each group with a server ID

Initially, the job IDs are equal to the server IDs. As servers are removed, servers will handle multiple jobs.

In other words, you just add a small indirection `client -> job -> server` so that your operations touch only the first or only the second arrow.

Comment: I didn't say it but I can't assume nothing about the system at the start. Meaning, I could have K servers and n requests but all requests are handled just by one server out of the K I got. So saying that "Initially, the job IDs are equal to the server IDs" is not a good assumption.

Comment: In that case, your clients will be handled by a single job ID at first. The job IDs are just a proxy for server IDs. ("job" might not be an optimal choice of name.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a hash table (where each entry of the hash table is a reference to a list):

Let the size of the hash table be the smallest prime number (`p`) which is greater than K.

The hash function for a requestID, then, would be `requestID % p`. This would make the complexity for `GetServer` O(1). However, the downside of this is that there is no balancing of requestIDs.